# How to insert multiple rows from JSON structure to MySQL column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, node-mysql

I need to insert multiple json value into a mysql column.
Here I have a table named client

```
query = ' INSERT INTO client (user_id,client_id,tenant_id) values ?'
let queryClient = []
queryClient.push(clientData.user_id)
queryClient.push(clientData.client_id);
queryClient.push(clientData.tenant_id);
```

Before that I assigned `req.body` into `clientData`

Here is the connection to the mysql database

```
var queryMapClientIn = mysql.format(query, [queryClient])
const newMapClient = await conPool.query(queryMapClientIn, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});
```

This is the code and json data is:

```
{
    "user_id" : 101,
    "client_id": 999,
    "tenant_id" : 1,
    "additionalClient" : [
        {"user_id" : 130},
        {"user_id" : 131}
    ]
}
```

Here is the json data and i need to push multiple `user_id` into `user_id` column on sql table. Can I get to know how to insert multiple `user_id` on this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a 2-dimensional array to insert multiple rows.

```
let clientData = {
    "user_id" : 101,
    "client_id": 999,
    "tenant_id" : 1,
    "additionalClient" : [
        {"user_id" : 130},
        {"user_id" : 131}
    ]
};
let queryClient = [[clientData.user_id, clientData.client_id, clientData.tenant_id]];
if (clientData.additionalClient) {
    let additionalClients = clientData.additionalClient.map(({user_id}) => [user_id, clientData.client_id, clientData.tenant_id]);
    queryClient = queryClient.concat(additionalClients);
}

let query = 'INSERT INTO client (user_id,client_id,tenant_id) values ?';
const newMapClient = await conPool.query(query, queryClient, function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
});
```

Comment: Its showing map is map is undefined and it cannot read the property. Can I know what is the use of map here

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: That means that there's no `clientData.additionalClient` property like you showed.

Comment: Read it carefully. It doesn't say that map is undefined, it says that `clientData.additionalClient` is undefined, since that's what we're trying to access the `map` property of.

Comment: I've updated the answer to add a check so it skips that part when there's no `additionalClient` array.

Comment: I initialised const clientData = { "additional_client" : req.body.additionalClient }

Comment: `additional_client` != `additionalClient`

Comment: In the question you say you just do `clientData = req.body`

Comment: Anyway, it should be obvious that you just need to make the code match the actual property names that you're using. The idea is the same.